# how to move pieces in a chess board

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a chess board and i'm stuck with moving the pieces. my function 'moving_pieces' not working as expected and i don't know why. here is the function.

```
function moving_pieces() {
    //getting pieces ids
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    let target_piece = null;
    images.forEach(img => {
        img.addEventListener('click', function handle_move () {
            target_piece = img;
            console.log(img) //for debugging
        });
    });

    //getting squares ids
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
    let target_square = null;
    squares.forEach(square => {
        square.addEventListener('click', function handle_id() {
            if (!square.firstChild) {
                target_square = square;
                console.log(square) //for debugging
            }
        });
    });
    target_square.appendChild(target_piece);
}
```

for future readers.

EDIT: i edited my variable scopes and now it's fine but the pieces still not moving.

EDIT 2: i found the problem. i have to put the `target_square.appendChild(target_piece);` inside of `squares.forEach`
and it work just fine, happy coding :)

what i'm trying to do is to get the piece id and square id and then append the piece in that square.
i succeeded in getting the ids but the piece is not moving.

Comment: target_square and target_piece are set when your eventListeners are triggered, not when your moving_piece function is called, so that last line won't work. You'll probably also need to set the second eventlistener from the first one and take care of your variables' scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are declaring the `target_square and target_piece` inside the loops. Try moving the declaration outside the loops. Like this:

```js
function moving_pieces() {
    //getting pieces ids
    let images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    let target_piece = null;
    images.forEach(img => {
        img.addEventListener('click', function handle_move () {
            target_piece = img;
            console.log(img.parentElement) //for debugging
        });
    });

    //getting squares ids
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
    let target_square = null;
    squares.forEach(square => {
        square.addEventListener('click', function handle_id() {
            if (!square.firstChild) {
                target_square = square;
                console.log(square) //for debugging
            }
        });
    });
    target_square.appendChild(target_piece);
}
```

I created a far from perfect example on how to move an element to a new square. In my case it's just an 'X' and the code is far from complete for what you need but it might give you some insights :)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nekcoj/pen/XWEgGNj)

Comment: yes thanks for your help. now vscode is happy but the pieces still doesn't move so is it because of this function of something else?

Comment: thanks for your effort i appeciate it. i found the bug, it was a logical error
i would have to put `target_square.appendChild(target_piece);` inside `squares.forEach`

Comment: here's the whole source code if want to look at it. https://github.com/AbdallahNagy/ChessGame